# Create a valid shared library in C

Tags: c, dll, compilation, shared-libraries, loadlibrary

I'm doing some test to learn how to create shared library.
The template for shared libraries in Code::Blocks is this

library.c

```
// The functions contained in this file are pretty dummy
// and are included only as a placeholder. Nevertheless,
// they *will* get included in the shared library if you
// don't remove them :)
//
// Obviously, you 'll have to write yourself the super-duper
// functions to include in the resulting library...
// Also, it's not necessary to write every function in this file.
// Feel free to add more files in this project. They will be
// included in the resulting library.

// A function adding two integers and returning the result
int SampleAddInt(int i1, int i2)
{
    return i1 + i2;
}

// A function doing nothing ;)
void SampleFunction1()
{
    // insert code here
}

// A function always returning zero
int SampleFunction2()
{
    // insert code here

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to compile it, and it compiled without any error or warning. But when i tried to use it with the ctyped.cdll.LoadLibrary("library path.dll") in python 3(that actually should work like the C function), it said that it wasn't a valid win32 application. Both python and code::blocks are 32 bit (code:blocks compile with gcc, and i tryed to use an installed version of mingw on my system, but it gives some error about a missing library) while i'm working on win 7 64bit

Do you know what the problem can be, or if i'm doing something wrong?

EDIT1:
i'm on windows 7 64bit, in the specs file of the compiler is wrote: "Thread model: win32, gcc version 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)"
and i used as command

```
gcc.exe -shared -o library.dll library.c
```

in python i used

```
from ctypes import *

lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\Francesco\\Desktop\\C programmi\\Python\\Ctypes DLL\\library.dll")
```

and the error was

```
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

i installed both python3.1 and mingw from the binary package and not compiling them on my system

EDIT2:
After reading Marc answer.

main.h

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <windows.h>

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

DLL_EXPORT int MySimpleSum(int A, int B);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

main.c

```
#include "main.h"

// a sample exported function
DLL_EXPORT int MySimpleSum(int A, int B)
{
    return A+B;
}
```

compiling options

```
gcc -c _DBUILD_DLL main.c
gcc -shared -o library.dll main.o -Wl,--out-implib,liblibrary.a
```

with gcc 4.5.2
still get the same error..

Comment: what compiler/OS/IDE are you using?

Comment: There may be something wrong in the way you link it, you may be missing some other .dlls you linked against or there might be a mismatch in compiler and linker options between your library and python. You'll need to provide the compiler and linker commands you used to build the library if you want more specific diagnosis.

Comment: Compiler, OS, and IDE are all in the question.

Comment: Added more information to make things clearer

Comment: maybe add -fPIC to the gcc command?

Comment: Also, but kinda unrelated: your compiler version is stone-age-old. Go to the mingw sourceforge site and find a newer one. the latest version in 4.5.1 I think.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma Tried with 
gcc.exe -c -fPIC library.c
gcc.exe -shared -o library.dll -fPIC library.o
But still get the same error..

Comment: You're using windows native python or mingw python?

Comment: @hlynur native for win @rubenvb i know, but while installing the update mingw it gave me some problem, now solved, but the problem remains

Comment: rrrite, IMHO you should use native libraries with native python. Download Dev-C++, build a shared library(perhaps there is already a project template for that in IDE) and try the python code with the new dll file is what I would do.

Comment: @hlynur i already use wxDev-C++ (that is still developed), but when i try to create a dll project it crashes.. And when i try to install dev-cpp 5(beta) it says that is better not to install on a previous version..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in the windows environment you need to use the `__declspec` annotation. How to create a shared library and the use of `__declspec` is described here: [DLL Creation in MingW](http://sig9.com/node/35).

Comment: @Makers_F There may be further problems with stdcall vs cdecl; but this is a guess and it seems unlikely. You can read more [Stdcall and DLL tools of MSVC and MinGW](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/stdcall.htm), and here: [MinGW - Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~zeil/cgi-bin/diffs/new_http___www.mingw.org_mingwfaq.shtml). I hope if nothing else these are useful resources.