# Create a shared library in C for java

Tags: java, c, mingw-w64

When I try to use my library.dll with java I have this error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\ledev\Desktop\library.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2424)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2481)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2678)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2643)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:876)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1875)
    at JNI.HelloJNI.<clinit>(HelloJNI.java:6)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Here is my code main.c :

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


DLL_EXPORT void hello_jni()
{
    printf("Hello, JNI !");
}
```

Here is my main.h :

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__
#define BUILDING_DLL

#include <windows.h>

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


#ifdef __c
extern "C"
{
#endif

DLL_EXPORT void hello_jni();

#ifdef __c
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

And here is my java code :

```
package JNI;

public class HelloJNI {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("library");
    }

    private native void hello_jni();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HelloJNI().hello_jni();  // invoke the native method
    }
}
```

This is how I created my dll :

```
g++ -c -BUILD_DLL main.c
g++ -shared -o library.dll main.o -Wl,--out-implib,libexample_dll.a
```

I'm working under intellij IDEA for java and none particular IDE for my c code. My os is windows 10.
I don't really know what I have to modifiy to make it works. None of the topics I read helped me (for exemple : [Create a valid shared library in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233056/create-a-valid-shared-library-in-c)). If you need anything else, just tell me.

Comment: `Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform` in your exception should be the clue

Comment: @soufrk I saw it, but I can't figure out what I have to change to create a 64-bit .dll

Comment: You need a 64-bit compiler.

Comment: Ok, so I change this : 

   ` g++ -c -BUILD_DLL main.c` and 
    `g++ -shared -o library.dll main.o -Wl,--out-implib,libexample_dll.a`

Into :
    `g++ -m64 -c -BUILD_DLL main.c` and 
    `g++ -m64 -shared -o library.dll main.o -Wl,--out-implib,libexample_dll.a`